# By this tomorrow, I will have the information you need vs By this time tomorrow, I will have had the information you need

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar, tense

I wonder if the two sentences below could be interpreted based on context or if one is more appropriate than the other.

-By this time tomorrow, I **will have** the information you need
-By this time tomorrow, I **will have had** the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the first if you are trying to convey to someone that you don't have the information, but will tomorrow. The second doesn't really work at all (I'm guessing). "I will have had" implies you no longer have the information.

To get a sentence more similar in theme to your second, you could use "By this time tomorrow, I will have already gotten/received/obtained the information you need".